# Como tratar cada valor de um array sem saber o nome do índice?

Tags: php, array

É o seguinte, estou criando uma função que recebe um array e transforma o escrito em uppercase, o código é o seguinte:

```
function uppercase($post_array) //ok
{
    $post_array['clienteNomeCompleto'] = mb_strtoupper($post_array['clienteNomeCompleto']);

    return $post_array;
}
```

Bem ai que está o problema, neste exemplo, eu sei que o valor está no campo clienteNomeCompleto, mas os outros campos eu não sei o nome, pois a mesma função irá receber dados de 3 listas diferentes, uma de clientes, outra de fornecedores, e outra de funcionários, cada uma com campos específicos, dai eu queria saber, como faço para fazer isso sem precisar especificar o nome do campo?
Eu tentei assim:

```
function uppercase($post_array)
{
    $post_array = mb_strtoupper($post_array);
    return $post_array;
}
```

E assim:

```
function uppercase($post_array) //ok
{
    $count = count($post_array)
   for( $i=0; i<=$count; $i++){
   mb_strtoupper($post_array[$i]);
   }
    return $post_array;
}
```

Até com um foreach eu tentei:

```
    function uppercase($post_array) //ok
{
    foreach ($post_array as $value){
    $value = mb_strtoupper($value);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz, no que eu estou fazendo errado?
E se não for incomodo, como faço a mesma função, só que para retirar os caracteres ,.;:/?\|-_()[]{} também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, use `array_map`. Ele mapeia cada item do `array` aplicando a função desejada:

```
$post_array = array_map('mb_strtoupper', $dados);
```

A forma que você tentou com `foreach` daria certo se tivesse usado referência no valor.

```
function array_to_upper_case(array $post_array) {

    foreach ($post_array as &$value) {
        $value = mb_strtoupper($value);
    }

    return $post_array;
}
```